# Parametric Models

Tags: scripting, file-format

In the [KiCad](https://kicad-pcb.org/) project, we ship 3D models of electronic components so people can do a rendered or raytraced preview of their PCB before sending it off to manufacture.

Several of the models are rather repetitive, for example the models for [pin headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pin_header) exist in 1x1, 1x2, 1x3, ... 1x30, 2x1, 2x2, 2x3, ..., 2x30, 3x1, 3x2, 3x3, ..., 3x30 variants, and each of these for multiple common configurations of pin pitch and thickness.

These are currently generated with a script, which generates a lot of output, and is difficult to maintain.

Is there a way in Blender to build a parametric model, ideally in a way that remains editable? Typical parameters would be distances, loop counts, texts and colors (e.g. for rings on [resistors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor)).

OpenSCAD comes close to what we need, but is difficult to use and doesn't generate material information, which makes the models unusable for rendering.

Comment: Simple answer is yes.  For example add a cylinder, change the amount of verts in ring and depth.

Comment: @batFINGER, to clarify, we need to be able to set the parameters when importing the model into another tool, so we'd have to be able to use a variable name there, and somehow find out from our tool what variables exist.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the kind of data you want to start from? Is it geometry or a text description of the board?

Comment: @EdTate, we usually have a mechanical drawing for the geometry, with a table on how different variants differ (e.g. pin count, pin thickness, pin pitch). The answer by Martynas Žiemys gets one of the problems, pin count of a header, right, but we need to be able to fill in the actual pin count when we load the model (which we currently do through OCC/OCE) so we don't have to ship each variant as a separate file. Some other models need more than simple repetition, e.g. ICs with different pin counts also need the package itself elongated.

Comment: Can the exporter generate a text file describing the geometry wanted and the location?

Comment: @EdTate, our program can already load VHDL and STEP models, and combine them to a full scene, e.g. [one of my boards](http://psi5.com/~geier/led_driver.jpg). The layout is easy, since all components are on the same plane, and we have coordinates on that plane from the placement data. What is missing is a way for people to prepare models for individual components in a way that allows us to use a single definition for multiple variants of a component, and especially a way to keep those definitions editable.

Comment: E.g. we have a model for a 2x3 pin header that is generated from an OpenSCAD file by compiling to CSG and adding materials, then saving as VRML. If a designed wanted to improve that model, importing the VRML is no good because it is not the original model -- you'd have to edit the OpenSCAD file. We're looking for a workflow in which the original model could be made in a 3D design tool, specific variants generated on first use (ideally with a cheap process that doesn't require a full installation of the design tool) and original models remain editable in the design tool.

Comment: Is the goal to have a process in blender to 1) define parametric components and 2) create the geometry for a specific part when needed? For example, a developer generates a parametric model for a resistor. Then, when needed, blender is invoked from the command line with a description of the resistor and exports the geometry for that part.

Comment: @EdTate, yes, with a preference that we didn't have to run Blender to instantiate the actual part, only to edit it -- most users don't edit components at all, just place them, and forcing them to install Blender for that would be excessive. I.e. if there is an export format that allows leaving the parameters undefined until use, we could write an import filter that would parse that, fill in the parameters, then hand it over to OCC/OCE.

Comment: The main reason I'm asking here is to get a feel for whether a workflow for designers already exists for something like that, so that we don't reinvent the wheel and make it more complex than necessary. I.e. there are volunteers who are somewhat familiar with Blender who'd take a specification like [TQFP144](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/packages/PG-TQFP/PG-TQFP-144-27/) and create a model from that, and ideally we'd be able to point them at a workflow that makes the model reusable for [TQFP100](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/packages/PG-TQFP/PG-TQFP-100-23/).

Comment: @SimonRichter, Blender exports in several formats (fbx, 3ds, obj, etc.). None of these formats appear support parametric models. The blender file format does contain all of the information needed to describe a parametric model. One workflow would be to create and edit a parametric model in blender, save the blend file, then create a custom importer to parse the model, parameters, and build the final object.

Comment: An open source blend file importer is available at https://www.blendernation.com/2016/01/05/java-blend/

Answer (score 1):

You can use modifiers like for example Array modifier to make it easier to model:

[image]

However if you wanted to have more control and trully parametric models, you would probably need to script the creation with Python(See Templates menu -> Python -> Addon Add Object in the Text Editor). Is it worth the trouble? It depends on what you are after. If you just need the parts modelled, it will be easier to model them and making them parametric will be extra work.

Comment: The goal is to stop shipping 5 GiB of prebuilt models in STEP files that only differ in parameters, and generate the required model on the fly from the template when it is first used -- for that the program importing the model needs to be able to specify the numbers later.

Comment: Then the answer is: it is possible to use Blender's Python API for generating 3d models proceedurally. Blender has bmesh Python module that has tools for working with geometry that might make things easier than programming/scripting from scratch. You can also have a look at [Animation Nodes](https://animation-nodes.com).